# scala 3 opaque type: cannot call methods defined in extension

Tags: scala, scala-3, opaque-types

I have this code mostly borrowed from the [Scala 3 book](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-opaque-types.html):

```
object Logarithms:
//vvvvvv this is the important difference!
  opaque type Logarithm = Double

  object Logarithm:
    def apply(d: Double): Logarithm = math.log(d)

  extension (x: Logarithm)
    def toDouble: Double = math.exp(x)
    def + (y: Logarithm): Logarithm = x + math.log1p(math.exp(y-x))
    def * (y: Logarithm): Logarithm = x + y
    //  vvvvvvvvv these two do not work!
    def toString: String = x.asInstanceOf[Logarithm].toDouble.toString
    def toString2: String = x.asInstanceOf[Logarithm].toDouble.toString
    //def toString: String = x.toDouble.toString // does not work either
```

The problem is that I cannot make toString work, it does not convert the value from the internal representation:

```
$ ~/Downloads/scala3-3.1.3/bin/scala
Welcome to Scala 3.1.3 (14.0.1, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).

scala> import Logarithms.*
                                                                                                                           
scala> Logarithm(4)
val res0: Logarithms.Logarithm = 1.3862943611198906   <<== the internal representation
                                                                                                                           
scala> Logarithm(4).toDouble
val res1: Double = 4.0                                <<== as expected
                                                                                                                           
scala> Logarithm(4).toDouble.toString
val res2: String = 4.0                                <<== as expected
                                                                                                                           
scala> Logarithm(4).toString
val res3: String = 1.3862943611198906                 <<== expected: 4.0 !!!
                                                                                                                           
scala> Logarithm(4).toString2
val res4: String = 1.3862943611198906                 <<== expected: 4.0 !!!
```

**How do I define toString without copying the code inside `toDouble` ?**

UPD with

```
def toString: String = "log:"+x.asInstanceOf[Logarithm].toDouble.toString
def toString2: String = "log:"+x.asInstanceOf[Logarithm].toDouble.toString
```

I get

```
scala> Logarithm(4).toString
val res0: String = 1.3862943611198906               <<== expected: log:4.0
                                                                                                                           
scala> Logarithm(4).toString2
val res1: String = log:1.3862943611198906           <<== expected: log:4.0
```

Comment: AFAIK is not possible, an `extension` will never shadow a method defined in the type, and all types define `toString` because of `Any`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the part of your question

> How do I define toString without copying the code inside `toDouble`?

Just don't call it "`toDouble`". In the context where the opaque type is known to be `Double`, the `toDouble` method will be interpreted as just the usual `Double#toDouble` (i.e. it will do nothing). If you rename your `toDouble` to something like `toLinear` (for internal use inside of `toString2`), then the `toLinear` will not collide with the built-in `toDouble`, and your `toString2` works as expected:

```
opaque type Logarithm = Double

object Logarithm:
  def apply(d: Double): Logarithm = math.log(d)

extension (x: Logarithm)
  private def toLinear: Double = math.exp(x)
  def toDouble: Double = toLinear
  def toString2: String = s"Logarithm(${x.toLinear.toString})"

println(Logarithm(4.0).toString2) // Logarithm(4.0)
```

You can't do anything about the `toString` though, because `toString` is defined on `AnyRef` / `java.lang.Object`, and you just can't get rid of it. You could try to use a `Show` typeclass instead, depending on how well it would fit into your project.